# html/js: how to get username of local system in html or in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a desktop application in html.

Now I want to get the username of the current user of the local system.

I do this in php:-

```
$wand = getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH")
```

but now I want to make this in html so it does need a server.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs in the context of the current HTML document, so it won't be able to determine anything about a current user unless it's in the current page or you do AJAX calls to a server-side script to get more information.

JavaScript will not be able to determine your Windows user name.

To do using AJAX:

```
request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'form.php',
        data: { }});

        request.done( function(response) {
    alert (response)}
        })

});
```

On form.php Side:

```
<?php>
$wand = getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH")
echo $wand;
?>
```

Comment: how to do this on ajax?

Comment: Make an AJAX request to the server, and get the username in response. Like, as you mention the way to do it in PHP

Answer (score 0):

**.php file**

```
<h1><?php echo getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH"); ?></h1>
```

Or you can declare the variable first

```
<?php $wand = getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH"); ?>
<h1><?php echo $wand; ?></h1>
```

**.html file**  You can use jquery ajax

```
<h1 id="username"></h1>
$( "#username" ).load( "/username.php" );
```

username.php

```
<?php echo getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH"); ?>
```